# Treating MongoDB Database as a SQL Database File (.mdf & .db Files)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, deployment, google-cloud-functions

I'm new to MongoDB. I'm trying to create a Node.js API that uses MongoDB and deploy it using Firebase Functions. In SQL there was a .mdf file or .db file holding the database. My Question is, is there a file like that in MongoDB i can grab and deploy with my API? or how can i deploy the database I've been working on locally on my PC with my Node.js API to the server i'm hosting on which in this context Firebase functions?

Thank you in advance. and sorry if my question isn't so clear.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a single file, there is a directory of them.  You'll want to copy all of the files in the dbpath, except the diagnostic.data and any log files.